# Getting an image from a database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, upload, insert

first time using stack overflow.

I have followed the following 2 part youtube tutorial on uploading/storing an image in a MYSQL database. I have followed the instructions but my image is not appearing for me. I use connect.php to connect to the database, this appears to be working fine. It seems the problem is with get.php as when I test echoing any images from it I always get no image.
 used phpmyadmin to create the database and am using xampp.

here is the link to the youtube tutorials

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CxY3FR9doHI

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFZfJZ_WNC4&feature=fvwrel

Included are the files

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload an image</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    File:   
<input type="file" name="image"> <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>

<?php

include 'connect.php';



//file properties
$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

if(!isset($file))
    echo "Please select an image.";
else{

    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
    $image_name=addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

    if ($image_size==FALSE)
        echo "That's not an image.";
    else{
            if(!$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO store       VALUES('','$image_name','$image')"))
        echo"Problem uploading image";
    else{
        $lastid = mysql_insert_id();

        echo "image uploaded.<p />your image:<p /><img src=get.php?id=$lastid>";
        }
    }
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is get.php

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

$id=stripslashes($_REQUEST('id'));
$image = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM store WHERE id=$id");
$image = mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
$image=$image('image');

header("content-type: image/jpeg");


?>
```

And finally connect

```
<?php
// connect to database

$db_host="localhost";
$db_username="root";
$db_pass="";
$db_name="test";

@mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die("Could not connect to      mysql");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("Cant find database");

?>
```

Comment: I see that you're suprsessing errors in at least one place (the `@` symbol).  Are you checking return values at all?  Checking your error log?

Comment: `$_REQUEST('id')` should be `$_REQUEST['id']` as well

Comment: +1 for a good first question that included all relevant code and with a good amount of information.

Answer (score 4):

Your `get.php` doesn't `echo $image`.
Also `$image=$image('image');` should be `$image=$image['image'];`, and `$_REQUEST('id')` should be `$_REQUEST['id']`.

P.S. Don't use `addslashes` to prevent against SQL injections.  Use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string).

Answer (score 1):

You never echo the image data in get.php, so you're serving a blank 0-byte image.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a line after the header output

```
header("content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $image;
```

Answer (score 0):

Very quick glance, in get.php change:

`$image=$image('image');`

to

`$image=$image['image'];`

mysql_fetch_assoc() converts the results into an array.

Comment: -1 There's enough code to justify more than a "quick glance", if that's all the time you can spare then why answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

You better of bas64_encoding an decoding that way none ansi chars wont create a problem.

`base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));`

This is wrong as array is [] not ()
    include 'connect.php';

```
$id=stripslashes($_REQUEST('id'));
$image = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM store WHERE id=$id");
$image = mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
$image=$image['image'];

header("content-type: image/jpeg");
echo base64_decode($image);
```

Answer (score -2):

Piece of code I use in a site of mine:

```
<?php
ob_start();
require_once("db.php.lib");

DBLogin();
$sql = "select pic_user_id, pic_full_data as bindata, pic_full_mime as mime, pic_full_size as size from pics where pic_name = '".urldecode($_GET["pic_name"])."'";

$result = DBExec($sql);
if ($result)
{
  $row = DBGetNextRow($result);
  if ($row)
  {
    header("Content-type: ".$row["mime"]);
    header("Content-length: ".$row["size"]);
    ob_clean();
    echo $row["bindata"];
    ob_end_flush();
  }
}
?>
```

It looks like you're leaving out the actual output of the image data, and the length might be required by some browsers...

Comment: Sorry but how does this help the user, that means nothing to him when he has got his completely different